# Regex: find last occurance of word in string

Tags: regex, unix

I need to find last occurance of a word in a string (and replace it). So in following sentence I would be looking for the second "chocolate".

> I love milk chocolate but I hate white **chocolate**.

How can that be achieved with regular expression? Could you please give me some explanation?
Thanks.

Comment: Why use regex at all for this?

Comment: Specifying the language you are using might be useful as well. But, for example, in Python, you could use `targetstring = "I love milk chocolate but I hate white chocolate"; targetstring.rfind("chocolate")`...

Comment: Why? Because school, that's why. It should be done in some unix text utility, for example sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a regex you could use something like this:

```
(.*)chocolate
```

And the replacement string would be:

```
$1banana
  ^-- whatever you want
```

**[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC2lM1/1)**

[image]

**Update:** as **[Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764814/lucas-trzesniewski)** pointed out in his comment, you can improve the regex by using:

```
(.*)\bchocolate\b
```

This allows you to avoid false positives like `chocolateeejojo`

Comment: @AdamSmith checked that and it's working fine. Check it https://regex101.com/r/cC2lM1/2. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Hrm, no, I'm just expecting behavior that doesn't exist! Sorry about that :)

Comment: Your regex will replace the first one in certain cases.

Comment: @ZachLeighton No, my regex uses a greedy quantifier, it will capture everything but last. I provided a working demo link, you can check it there :)

Comment: @Fede whoops my mistake

Comment: @Zach nope, `.*` is greedy and will eat up the whole input before backtracking util it reaches the last occurence. I'd just wrap `chocolate` between `\b` anchors.

Comment: Note that `\b` as a word boundary is vendor-specific and not necessarily portable.  For portability, it's better to use the true word boundary classes, `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

PCRE would look like this:

`/^(.*)chocolate/$1replace/sm`

Comment: `(.*?)$` is useless, just drop it along with `$2` and it'll work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the second occurrence of any distinct word, you may be able to use a backreference, depending on the language and regex implementation you're in.

For example, in `sed`, you might do the following:

```
sed 's/\(.*\([[:<:]][[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]\).*\)\(\2\)\(.*\)/\1russians\4/'
```

Breaking this down for easier reading, it looks like this:

- `s/` - substitute in sed
- `\(.*\([[:<:]][[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]\).*\)\(\2\)\(.*\)` - the search RE. Not really so complex....

  - `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are portable word boundaries,
  - `[[:alpha:]]` is the class of alphabetical characters (words)
  - `\(` and `\)` surround atoms for use in backreferences, in BRE (this is sed, remember)
- `\1russians\4` - replacement string consists of the first (outer) parenthesized backreference from the RE, followed by the replacement word, followed by the trailing characters.

For example:

```
$ t="I love milk chocolate but I hate white chocolate."
$ sed 's/\(.*\([[:<:]][[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]\).*\)\(\2\)\(.*\)/\1russians\4/' <<<"$t"
I love milk chocolate but I hate white russians.
$ t="In a few years, your twenty may be worth twenty bucks."
$ sed 's/\(.*\([[:<:]][[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]\).*\)\(\2\)\(.*\)/\1fifty\4/' <<<"$t"
In a few years, your twenty may be worth fifty bucks.
$
```